# How to order SQLite-results containing umlauts and other special characters?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to order my results from SQLite according to the rules used for German. This means a character like "�" is treated like "ae", or "�" like "ue".

At this point the solution looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(einrichtung),'�','AE'),'�','OE'),'�','UE') LIMIT 0,20
```

The solution should not involve installing more tools or modifying the SQLite service, because this project should run "out of the box" wherever it will be deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do everything in UTF-8/UTF-16.
If you are dealing with PHP for example you have also work with utf8_encode/utf8_decode.

See also http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding

*(I know the question is old, but people still having problems with proper encoding.)*

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and it is still not possible.

This is a quote from the FAQ of sqlite.org:

> Q: Case-insensitive matching of Unicode characters does not work.
>
> A: The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive comparisons of ASCII 
>   characters. The reason for this is that doing full Unicode
>   case-insensitive comparisons and case conversions requires tables and
>   logic that would nearly double the size of the SQLite library. The
>   SQLite developers reason that any application that needs full Unicode
>   case support probably already has the necessary tables and functions
>   and so SQLite should not take up space to duplicate this ability.
>   Instead of providing full Unicode case support by default, SQLite
>   provides the ability to link against external Unicode comparison and
>   conversion routines. The application can overload the built-in NOCASE
>   collating sequence (using sqlite3_create_collation()) and the built-in
>   like(), upper(), and lower() functions (using
>   sqlite3_create_function()). The SQLite source code includes an "ICU"
>   extension that does these overloads. Or, developers can write their
>   own overloads based on their own Unicode-aware comparison routines
>   already contained within their project.

Answer (score -4):

Hey, it's the third millenium, dude, there are no special characters anymore - just characters.

That said, it seems you want to change the collation behaviour among those characters. [This extension](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt) can probably help you. If you don't like any of the provided collations, I think you can program one yourself, as described
[here](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_create_collation)

Comment: Yeah, I wish they were no special characters anymore. But just look at the umlauts in my posting. :)

Thx for your answer, but I was hoping there would be a solution without recompiling SQLite or installing any other tools. But the more I search for such a solution, the more I think there is none. :(