# iOS sqlite3 order by LOWER() not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a table which consists of 3 video name :

```
V for vendetta
A fish story
İsmail where are you (İ is the capital of i in Turkish)
```

when I query this :

```
select * from videos order by LOWER(name) asc
```

in Mozilla Firefox SQLite Manager extension, it gives the correct ordering

```
A fish story
İsmail where are you
V for vendetta
```

But when I query this in my iOS application its ordering is false:

```
A fish story
V for vendetta
İsmail where are you
```

what can be the reason ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite Order By places umlauts & speical chars at end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850559/sqlite-order-by-places-umlauts-speical-chars-at-end)